# Return a Result from a for loop or nothing if there are no results

Tags: error-handling, rust

I want to return the `Result` as shown in below from the `for loop`. Please help which would be the best way solve this error. I tried the pattern matching with returning `None` which works. But I need to return `Error`.

```
pub fn get_account(&self) -> Result<Keys, Error> {
    //PATH is default home directory
    let values = match load_json_file(PATH + "/keys.json") {
        Ok(account) => Ok(account),
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(Error::Invalid_Tx(
                "The sender address cannot be nil".to_owned(),
            ))
        }
    };
    let accounts: Vec<Keys> = values.unwrap();
    let sender_address = self.sender.unwrap();
    for acc in accounts {
        if acc.address == sender_address {
            return Ok(acc);
        };
    };
    Ok(())
}
```

> expected struct `commands::key::Keys`, found `()`rustc(E0308)

Comment: so it sounds like you know what you need to do (return an error instead of `Ok(())`). What is the issue?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen: Maybe the OP is not aware that the last line `Ok(())` is an implicit returned value, as it lacks the final `;`, and that creates confusion, compared to the other more verbose `return Err(...)`?

Comment: hi thanks for replay, I want to return accounts from get_account method has result but get error ```expected struct `commands::key::Keys`, found `()```

Comment: @fama the problem is in the last line `Ok(())`, with that you say that you return nothing (in Rust it's written as `()` value). And "nothing" is not interchangeable with `Keys` type, so you need to return some kind of `Keys` value, e.g. a default value `Keys::default()` if the type implements `Default` trait

Comment: @fama or you may try to reuse some variant of your `Error` enum type, and then return `Err(Error::Something(...))` instead of `Ok(())`

Comment: If i return error it works, but is it good practice to return error, bcoz i don't have any default implementation for Keys.

Comment: @fama there are no strict practices on `Error` usage, but rather usage of `Option` vs `Error`. The former is to signal that "something went wrong, but the function may ever fail for only one reason, just check the documentation what is that", and the latter is to say that "the function failed, use pattern matching to determine what's wrong exactly". `Error` isn't strictly IO/network/system error, it's just a mere tool to report multiple possible errors with a single type. If your `Error` has a variant, or has a possibility to tell that "no account found", then just return such `Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return two different types from the same function:

- line 15: `Ok(acc)` is of type `Result<Keys, Error>`
- line 18: `Ok(())` has type `Result<(), Error>`

If "no result" is a valid return value, then you can change the function  signature to:

```
pub fn get_account(&self) -> Result<Option<Keys>, Error>;
```

And then modify those return values to be `Ok(Some(acc))` and `Ok(None)` respectively.

If "no result" is an error then you need to modify the `Error` type to include this variant. For example:

```
enum Error {
    Invalid_Tx(String),
    NotFound,
}
```

And return `Err(Error::NotFound)` at the end.

---

You can also tidy this function up a lot, by using `thiserror`, which is a popular crate for defining error types:

```
use thiserror::Error; // thiserror = "1.0.21"

#[derive(Debug, Error)]
enum Error {
    #[error("The sender address cannot be nil")]
    InvalidTx,
    #[error("The key was not found")]
    NotFound,
}

pub fn get_account(&self) -> Result<Keys, Error> {
    let accounts: Vec<Keys> = load_json_file(PATH + "/keys.json")
        .map_err(|_| Error::InvalidTx)?;
    let sender_address = self.sender.unwrap();
    accounts
        .into_iter()
        .find(|acc| acc.address == sender_address)
        .ok_or(Error::NotFound)
}
```

This is better because the `String`s in the errors do not need to be allocated, but they are still available as static string slices if they are needed for display. I also got rid of the `for` loop altogether, which makes the function shorter and cleaner.